# path for copy from HDFS with copyToLocal

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera

I am trying to copy from HDFS
when I run this nothing happens.

```
hadoop fs -copyToLocal out1 ~/datatemp
```

I am assuming I should include a longer path for the HDFS file?
`out1` is a directory stored on HDFS and `~/datatemp` is the destination directory on local disk.
I am doing it correctly? why is nothing appearing in `~/datatemp`? How do I know the full path to `out1`

I have also tried

```
hadoop fs -get out1 ~/datatemp
```

Comment: does  it  show  'copyToLocal: `out': No such file or directory'    ？

Comment: thank you for the replies.It was storing somewhere else. when I added a full path I was able to find my files

Comment: very glad  to help you

Answer (score 2):

To copy the entire `out1` HDFS directory to local disk:

```
hadoop fs -copyToLocal /hdfs/path/to/out1 ~/datatemp
```

To copy a file in `out1` HDFS directory, say `file1.txt`:

```
hadoop fs -copyToLocal /hdfs/path/to/out1/file1.txt ~/datatemp
```

To copy all files in `out1` HDFS directory:

```
hadoop fs -copyToLocal /hdfs/path/to/out1/* ~/datatemp
```

To find where `out1` directory is on HDFS, you can do a listing and search:

```
hadoop fs -ls -R / | grep out1
```

Answer (score 0):

For the people who is using a different version of Hadoop, you could use the hdfs dfs.

like this:

```
hdfs dfs -get hdfs:/path/to/hdfs/directory /home/local/directory
```